# Android (Tasker) - How to Emulate Back Button Function

Tags: java, javascript, shell, android-4.4-kitkat, tasker

I am looking into getting a second android phone, my current android phone has the Back, Home and Recent Apps buttons in a black bar at the bottom. The new doesn’t as they are all physical buttons.

I am not a huge fan of physical buttons and want to avoid wearing them out if possible, so am looking for a way to get tasker to trigger these functions at my command.

So for example, I have created an overlay which if pressed acts as a button taking me to the home screen.

Under New Tasker > Select Action Category > App > Go Home

But i cant find anyway of emulating the back function. I know it is possible without root because there are other apps on the market which are able to do the function i am after

Unfortunately I cant post links :(

Please see Google App Store;
Back Button (No root)
Button Savior Non Root
Handy Soft Keys

So these apps all provide “Soft keys” for hardware functions. I am looking for tasker to be able to do the back function.

**What I have done

Looked into every function in Tasker but cant find the answer

One thing i did find when going though hours on the net is this

"It looks like you can send a back button via the accessibility service.

might be a good addition for non-root users (GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK):

developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html"

but i wouldn't know how to apply this into tasker.

*Extra Information

Phone Sony Z1 Compact
KitKat 4.4
Not Root (I don't wish to root the phone either)

Comment: Your question is too broad as it is to get any real help. Please consider showing what you have tried and describing the specific problem that you need help with.

Comment: I have completely rewritten the question to hopefully make it less broad and easier for others to understand.

Comment: @IanN1990 here is the complete list of keycodes http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

I see a back button option in my tasker. When I start a new task choosing Input--Button--Back. Hope this helps. My phone is rooted, not sure if non-rooted see the same thing.

I stumbled onto your question because I'm looking to toggle the recent apps button, no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

This will emulate pressing the back button:

Select Action Category > Code > Run Shell

Command: input keyevent 4

For the recent apps button use

input keyevent 187

but this will only work with the "use root" option.